# SQL add percentage to value in calculation

Tags: sql, percentage

Ive seen a few examples on here to work out how to add a percentage to a value in sql, but they don't match if I actually do the calculation.

Ive tried "Value + (value * percentage)"

Any other examples I can try, I have a value column and a percentage column which will be used to work out the increased/decreased amount.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect to happen vs what is actually happening?

Comment: IF I had a value of 100 and I add percentage of 10% I should get 110 as the calculated value

Comment: add 1 to your percentage and multiply... `Value*(1+percentage)`  100*110% = 110...     9*(1+5%) = 9.45  (assuming not integer math.)  so it may depend on the data type of value. If integer you may have a problem if decimal you should be ok

Comment: from what I understand, you need `update table set value = value + (value * percentage) where <condition>`. If this is not the case,then you need to add some sample data and your expected output based on it.

Comment: @user3691566 But what is your query returning? And what are examples of `value` and `percentage`?

Comment: Thanks xQbert that was the answer I was looking for, it is a decimal value im using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to add a percentage to an existing value add 1 to the percentage and multiply by the value.

`Update table set value = value*(1+45%)`

100*110% = 110...

9*(1+5%) = 9.45...

8*(1+100%) = 16

2*(1+0%) = 2

This assumes the value in the table is decimal to begin with if integer, then you will end up with some rounding issues.

Answer (score 4):

So you need:

```
SELECT Value,Percentage,OtherColumns.....,VALUE + (value*percentage)/100 as newValue
FROM YourTable
```

If you need an update, it works the same way:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET VALUE = VALUE + (value*percentage)/100
```

You can add where clause to filter only a desired records